# An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.14)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

[screen shot of myerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX0TQ.png)   I Installed Mysql-server, libmysqlclient-dev, ruby-mysql, mysql-client, libmysqld-dev

But still this issue occurs.Could not continue my project.

Environment: rails version - 4.2.6 , ruby - 2.3, mysql - 5.7

Comment: What does the log show?

Comment: Can we get some output?

Comment: updated my screenshot. please look at it.

Comment: Look at where the results were logged to.  It will give you the errors

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and do `bundle install` again

Comment: Edit your `Gemfile` with `gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18'` and try again

Comment: got the result. worked fine. i forgot to install "sudo apt-get install ruby-dev" after this i tried bundle install. now working. thanks all..

Comment: your answer is correct that is also needed. could not raise your answer due to my points. ill update when i get 15 reputations.